# Search Results Sorting Recently Edited Items to the Bottom

Tags: product-list, search

If I search for a brand on my site, by default I get back all items of that brand, sorted by relevance. Since they all are the same brand and therefor equally relevant for that search, they are sorted by a second condition. This conditions appears to be when the item was last updated, in reverse. So whenever I change a product on the admin backend and save it, it then shows up at the bottom of the search list.

I want to find where this is being done, then reverse it so that the secondary sort put items most recently updated at the top of the results instead. Anyone have any ideas of where the relevant section of code may be found?

Comment: What version of Magento and is a 3rd party search solution involved like Solr, Elasticsearch or Sphinx?

Comment: You are talking about the advanced search, right?